# How do i get my wireless to work on a dell inspiron 6000?

Tags: wireless, 12.10, dell, inspiron

When I installed ubuntu, everything was working perfectly except for the wireless networks.  When i click on networks wireless is not an option.  I know my wireless works because it worked fine before on fedora and windows.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Start by typeing `lspci | grep Ethernet` and edit your question with the results. If this command gives no results try a plain `lspci` and locate the wifi adapter model.

Comment: Here are the results "03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)"

Comment: That's the cable network connection not the wifi. Try `lspci` again and fetch the wireless card type.

Comment: Is this it? "03:03.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open **Update Manager**
2. Open Settings
3. Go the the **Additional drivers tab**.
4. Check if a Broadcom proprietary driver is offered. Install it.
5. Reboot.

If that doesn't work, try following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#A11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29_-_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29-1).

In short:

1. Identify your card by typing in a terminal `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4`
2. Check which driver is suitable for you from [this list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Drivers_available_in_Ubuntu)
3. In your case (BCM4318) you need the b43 driver
4. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
5. Reboot.

Comment: It will not let me apply the changes do i have to be logged in as root?

Comment: Didn't it simply ask you for the sudo password?

Comment: It did not ask me.  However it did show one driver which is identified as Unkonwn with do not use checked and when i check Continue using as a manuel driver (the only avalible option that is clickable) it higlights red.

Comment: I would try the instructions in the link in my answer above installing the b43 driver.

Comment: I'm glad it did. Please mark it as the correct answer for the benefit of other users having the same problem.